# How to auto bind collection from HTML form using node.js express framework?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, pug, node.js-connect

I am looking for a way to bind a collection on the server side, for example:

**single binding**

```
<input type="text" name="person[name]" />
```

binds to

```
person:{
    name: 'Name from html form'
}
```

If I am using express I can have access to this object at:

```
app.post('/person', function(req, res){
    console.log(JSON.stringify(req.body.person, null, 2));
});
```

**collection binding**

But now I am looking for a way to have multiple phone numbers, for example, I want this JSON to arrive:

```
person:{
    name: 'Name from html form',
    phones: [
        { number: '12345678' },
        { number: '87654321' }
    ]
}
```

So what is the syntax for binding an input to a collection field???

I tried `<input type="text" name="person[phone][number]" />` with no success, and have no idea how to Google for it (I already tried, without success...). Is this a feature from express/connect? If not, what is the best way to achieve it? I know this feature is present on some Java frameworks, so this might exist here too.

Comment: You dont need an object , do you ? did you try just person[phone][] ? so it outputs number datas as an array ?

Comment: @camus - I am intended to have 0:Many phone numbers on the screen (form will be dinamically generated), so I cant hardcode `person[phone1][number]`... but I am giving your idea a try, then I post what happened!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @camus I found out the way to do it:

```
br
input(type="text", name="person[phones][0][type]")
input(type="text", name="person[phones][0][number]")

br
input(type="text", name="person[phones][1][type]")
input(type="text", name="person[phones][1][number]")
```

Gives the following at server side:

```
person: {
    phones:
    [{
        type: "1",
        number: "23453131"
    },
    {
        type: "2",
        number: "51254534"
    }]
}
```